# Is it possible to set rotation to the current meshes face?

Tags: modeling

On the image below I have an Icosphere that has been separated into multiple triangle objects. My only problem with this is that I need the rotations for them to all be facing the correct way, but every object has the same rotation. Is it possible to set them all to look the same but also have the rotation values that correctly point in the direction from the face?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is the larger task you are trying to achieve? Blender may have features that take care of your larger task without focusing on a smaller task.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you elaborate on: Is the axis in screenshot showing global or local or other space? What is the orientation you are after, z along the face normal and ...?  how did you arrive at current state, for instance does each object have a unique mesh.

Answer (score 1):

- Particles
- Duplicate Settings
- Explode Modifier

[image]

Particles with Rotation setting shown. Image Above.
Particles also has a billboard setting.  Particles can be made in real ... meaning into separate objects.